# webflow evaluate expression doesn't call method

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

in the flow:

```
<action-state id="create">
        <evaluate expression="operatore_rer" result="flowScope.operatore_rer" />
        <evaluate expression="mainService.getComuni()" result="flowScope.comuni_list" />
        <transition to="nuovo-operatore-rer" />
    </action-state>
```

evaluate expression doesn't call the method mainService.getComuni()

where and how i have to declare mainService????

if i declare this in applicationContext:

```
<bean id="mainService" class="com.aieap.services.MainService" />
```

this is the error:

```
GRAVE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mainService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatch-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.aieap.services.MainService]: Specified class is an interface
```

help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `@Service("mainService")` annotation to the class that implements the `MainService` interface and refer that class in the bean instead of interface. In that way the bean get's initialized and you can call that in your web flow.

Comment: questo è l'errore:org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mainService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/jdbc-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.aieap.services.MainService]: Specified class is an interface

Answer (score 0):

`mainService` has to be a bean known to Spring. Either through a Spring XML configuration file (which can be imported into your `flow.xml` file via `<bean-import>` or loaded through `web.xml`), or through annotation-based bean definition.

Comment: but on interface "MainService" there is a annotation @Service("mainService")